# Apply an Incremental Counter in an Array Function

Tags: loop, count

I'm attempting to incorporate an incremental counter inside an array function, that is, in turn, inside the post's while loop. However, I am only able to get it to count to 1.

This is what I currently have:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++ ) {
            webcomic_storylines_list( [
                'link'            => '<div class="media">{{%large}}</div>',
                'order'           => 'desc',
                'depth'           => 1,
                'webcomics_depth' => 0,
                'webcomics'       => [
                    'format' => '<div class="wrapper collapsed"><div class="overlay"></div>{{}}</div>',
                    'link'   => $i,
                    'order'  => 'asc'
                ]
            ] );
        }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

I've also tried placing the while loop inside the for loop, with no success.

The plugin used is Webcomic by Michael Sisk.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Apologies for the initial vagueness of my question.

What I would like to do is output webcomic posts (a custom post type created by the Webcomic plugin) with the following display in an archive:

Comic Pages:

1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4 ~ -5 ~ 6

etc., etc.

Each number relates to the page number of published webcomics and simply increases by 1 each time a webcomic is published. So the first webcomic post published would be page 1.

Essentially, what I am trying to create is a custom post type archive that is just a list of the page numbers and the page number is a link into the post itself.

The above code utilises a custom template tag created by the Webcomic plugin and is used in place of a template partic. The function and array are drawing from a custom taxonomy (again created by the plugin), which is basically categorisation of the webcomic pages. It is the `'link'` inside `'webcomics'` that outputs the post itself.

If one imagines a normal blog index might look like the below, I'd like to make this 'comic' index/archive look like what's on the right. Everything like chapter headings and the like are handled by the plugin -- it's just the page count I'm trying to implement.

```
+--------------------------+---------+    +-------------------------+---------+
|                          |         |    |                         |         |
|        Blog Index        |         |    |       Comic Index       |         |
|                          |         |    |                         |         |
| +---+  Title             |         |    |   Chapter 1             |         |
| |   |                    |         |    |                         |         |
| +---+  Excerpt...        | Sidebar |    |    1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4 ~ 5    | Sidebar |
|                          |         |    |    6 ~ 7 ~ 8 ~ 9 ~ 10   |         |
| +---+  Title             |         |    |                         |         |
| |   |                    |         |    |   Chapter 2             |         |
| +---+  Excerpt...        |         |    |                         |         |
|                          |         |    |    1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4 ~ 5    |         |
| +---+  Title             |         |    |    6 ~ 7 ~ 8 ~ 9 ~ 10   |         |
| |   |                    |         |    |                         |         |
| +---+  Excerpt...        |         |    |   Chapter 3             |         |
+--------------------------+---------+    +-------------------------+---------+
```

Finally, to be clear, the plugin does have the ability the output the post's title with `%title` in place of where `$i` currently is -- however, this would mean I'm unable to name the post/webcomic page anything other than a string of numerals.

The CPT is `webcomic`. Inside that CPT, there are a couple of custom taxonomies: `webcomic_storyline` is one of them and this is what dictates a 'chapter'. It is simply categorisation as we find with regular blog posts. A post is a webcomic 'page' and the storyline tax is a webcomic 'chapter'. So the function in my code is listing every 'chapter' (category) and then drawing every 'page' (post) that corresponds to that 'chapter'.

Comment: So for every post (`while`) you want `webcomic_storylines_list()` called 99 times (first with `'link' => 1` then `'link' => 2` until `'link' => 99`), do I understand this correct?

Comment: why are you incrementing counter again in link property? Simply put $i.

Comment: @kero Oops. Looks like I've missed that '99' when I copied my code across... I increased the number to 99 to check the counter (which, as expected, calls `webcomic_storylines_list()` and incrementally increases). I have edited my post accordingly and it is now back to '1'.

@JitenderSingh You're right -- $i++ is unneeded. Have edited my code to reflect this.

Comment: @Ash I still don't have any idea what you're trying to achieve. Can you elaborate more in the question?

Comment: @kero I do apologise for not being clear... I have edited my question, but I tend to think, after working at this a bit more, that I won't be able to achieve what I want.

Comment: @Ash We're getting there :) Just to be totally clear: You want the archive of your CPT to be 1 post per page with the page number corresponding to the `link` variable of the webcomics? I think that is entirely possible

Comment: @kero That's almost it... Though it's not so much that I'd like the CPT to be 1 post per page, since I'm looking to list every published comic page. If you think of WordPress' blog index, it often shows the post title, featured image and excerpt -- only in this case with my CPT, rather than each of those details, I just want a number indicating the page number, say in place of what might usually be the post title. The code I'm using is generated for each and every post. I've edited my question once more with an attempt at a visualisation of what I'm describing.

Comment: @Ash All right, the "picture" is great btw! So how does a post (i.e. the element you have inside the `while()`) correspond to chapters/pages (how do we know how many pages a chapter has)?

Comment: @kero OK, so the CPT is 'webcomic'. Inside that CPT, there are a couple of custom taxonomies: webcomic_storyline is one of them and this is what dictates a 'chapter'. It is simply categorisation as we find with regular blog posts. A post is a webcomic 'page' and the storyline tax is a webcomic 'chapter'. So the function in my code is listing every 'chapter' and then drawing every 'page' (post) that corresponds to that 'chapter'.

Comment: @Ash Ok, I think I got it. Sadly, I have to leave right now. I will take a look at this in an hour or so. Meanwhile I will try to reach a mod to reopen your question, as it is much clearer now what you want to achieve